# How do I call my baseUrl when I have multiple configuration files in Cypress?

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-configuration

I have a Cypress framework where I'm testing a user page (where they can interact with the page, download files, update their profile, etc.), and an admin page for that user page (separate login, and can actually, as an admin, modify what's in the user page).
For that reason, I have three configuration files:

1. `cypress.config-admin.ts`, where I have the baseUrl for the admin page (as in `www.mypage.admin.com`). I pass the --config-file tag in the `package.json` file for headless tests.
2. `cypress.config-user.ts` where I have the baseUrl for the user page (`www.mypage.com`). I pass the --config-file tag in the `package.json` file for headless tests.
3. `cypress-config.ts`, which I use to run the tests manually via Cypress dashboard.

There are times where I need to use both URLs in the same test case (do something as an admin, verify as a user).

My issue is, when I use `Cypress.config().baseUrl`, it only brings up the values on `cypress.config.ts`. I've tried multiple things, but I haven't found a way to call the baseUrl on the `admin` or `user` config files.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config seems to suggest I can pass the name of the configuration file, but I haven't been able to make that work =/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define the various `baseUrl` as env entries, then set them in the test as required.

This gives you a single config but access to multiple versions of baseUrl (presuming that's all you change in the various config versions).

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',   // default
  },
  env: {
    userBaseUrl: 'www.mypage.com',
    adminBaseUrl: 'www.mypage.admin.com',
  },
})
```

**Test:**

```js
it('tests with the admin page', 
  {baseUrl: Cypress.env('adminBaseUrl')},   // per-test configuration

  () => {
    const userBaseUrl = Cypress.env('userBaseUrl')    // access urls for test
    const adminBaseUrl = Cypress.env('adminBaseUrl')  

    // or configure on the fly
    Cypress.config('baseUrl', adminBaseUrl)
    cy.visit('/')                           // goes to adminBaseUrl

    // or use the env setting directly
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('adminBaseUrl'))

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I deleted my previous question since I figured it out. This is exactly what I was looking for